# Why I get a nullPointerExeption?

Tags: java, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I hope you can help me. I get an NullPointerExeption when I want to Put the NodeList / Node to my Map:

```
Map <String, NodeList> config = null; 

public void loadConfiguration() {
    helper helper = new helper();
    NodeList nodes = null;
    nodes = helper.getXPathFromFile("/root/*", "conf/config.xml");

    if (nodes.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            String NodeName = nodes.item(i).getNodeName();
            NodeList NodeItem = (NodeList) nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println(NodeName); // Here the right Name puts out
            System.out.println(helper.nodelistToString(NodeItem)); // here right inside XML-Code put out
            config.put(NodeName, NodeItem); // Here comes the NullPointerEx.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugging always helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map `config` is `null`, that's why you get the `NullPointerException`. You should initialize it e.g. `Map <String, NodeList> config = new HashMap <String, NodeList>();`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never initialize your `config` map.

Change

```
Map <String, NodeList> config = null;
```

to

```
Map <String, NodeList> config = new HashMap<String, NodeList>;
```

Comment: Is that kind of question worth to be answered ?